# Why can't I get the workbook's directory?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find the current directory of the workbook, since the location will change periodicly. But, the returned path is in the temporary folder and not where the file is located. I've tried it both of these ways.

```
folderPath = Replace(ThisWorkbook.FullName, templateBook, "")
```

OR

```
folderPath = ThisWorkbook.path
```

They both work the first time I run the macro, but when I close the workbook and move it I get the same problem.

NOTE: I'm using excel 2007.

Comment: Is this workbook created from a template file? Has it been saved at the moment you are calling this code? A little more background might help you get a better answer. If it was me,I'd assume that the workbook is actually where the code says it is, and figure out why.

Comment: The workbook is not a template. It has been saved and moved into a new folder when it is called. The code works until I move it into a new folder.

Comment: FYI: "current directory" and the "directory of the workbook" are two entirely different things.  From your description, I believe that you mean the latter.

Comment: Can you post some code that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: ''Receive month/year inputs Year = YearBox.Value Month = monthBox.Value 'Get name of template templateBook = ActiveWorkbook.Name 'Create new folder w/ month/year name folderPath = Replace(ActiveWorkbook.FullName, templateBook, "") & Month & " " & Year MkDir (folderPath)'

Comment: I discovered it is returning the temporary version of the workbook and not the orginal. I tried turning off the recovery, but it is still making the temporary workbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following code:

```
folderPath = CurDir("M") & "\" & Month & " " & Year
MkDir (folderPath)
```

I think it was not working the other ways because there is protection on the shared drive (M).